# extract text from html with python xpath

Tags: python, html, xpath

I want to extract the price of a player in futbin. Some part of the html  is here:

```
<div class="pr pr_pc" id="pr_pc">PR: 10,250 - 150,000</div>
<div id="pclowest" class="hide">23500</div>
```

I´ve programmed this with python:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('https://www.futbin.com/18/player/15660/Mar%C3%A7al/')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

player = tree.xpath('//*[@id="pclowest"]')
print 'player: ',  player
```

I want to extract the value 23500 automatically, but i cannot. Someone can help me?

Edit:

Theres another piece of code where data maybe can be extracted:

```
<div class="bin_price lbin">
  <span class="price_big_right">
    <span id="pc-lowest-1" data-price="23,000">23,000 <img alt="c" class="coins_icon_l_bin" src="https://cdn.futbin.com/design/img/coins_bin.png">
    </span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Could be possible to extract data-price here?

Comment: Post edited, Im sorry for my mistake

Comment: This value generated dynamically - you will not be able to scrape it with `requests`

Comment: there´s no way to extract this data? Any way?

Comment: With selenium or other tool that can handle JavaScript execution